# How come the following set of vectors is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

[image]

I row reduced this to

[image]

and now I'm not sure where to go from here. I know that if we have the last row of a matrix as

$0 0 0  0| 0 $

then there are infinitely many solutions (.e. linearly dependent), and for example if we have

$0 0 0 1 | 0 $

then there are no solutions (linearly independent). But what if we have

$0011|0$

as we do in this question, then what does that imply?

Comment: There are four of them.  There can't be more than $3$ independent $3$-vectors.

Comment: In general, any set of $n+1$ vectors in an $n$ dimensional vector space is linearly dependent. Specifically any four three dimensional vectors are linearly dependent.
For row reduction you need the vectors to be the rows, meaning you have your matrix inversed. Try inversing it and doing row reduction.

Comment: @KessemClein Hi Kessem, do you mean inverse or transpose?

Comment: @Programmer transpose :) sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb you are using for counting solutions only applies for *square* systems of equations.

It's better to compare the number of (independent) equations to the number of variables — in this case you have three pivots and four variable, which means a one-dimensional solution space.

You could salvage your rule of thumb by remembering to add extra zero rows to your system of equations (exercise: prove that doesn't change the solution space) to make it square.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting your row-reduced matrix.  There are infinitely many solutions to the corresponding system because (i) the system is consistent (the zero-vector is a solution); and (ii) there is a column that doesn't have a row-leading $1$ in it.

Note: $0000\mid 0$ doesn't necessarily mean infinitely many solutions--it depends on the rest of the matrix.  What you can say is that $0000\mid a$ where $a\ne 0$ implies no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The column vectors of a matrix are linearly independent iff the number of the columns equals the rank of the matrix.  In your case we have four vectors, but their rank is three.